# ZAP API scan Android and iOS devices

Tags: python, docker, zap

I'm trying to call the ZAP API with Python. I already found a guide from ZAP but if I understood it correctly there is no tutorial to scan Android and iOS via the Python API. Is there a solution in the docs or somewhere else to execute a, for example, scan on apks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZAP cannot scan apks files.
ZAP can only be used to scan apps that have an http(s) interface.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I found MobSF as a scanner for mobile devices.